# Idea PyCharm database tool returns same result for MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, intellij-idea, pycharm

Using PyCharm database tool for a mysql database over SSH tunnel.

I simply `select * from table_x` however database tool returns the same result (even after insertions/updates to the table). I double checked all the cache options, all off.

I tried different queries such as `select ... from table_x where id > ...` on the same table but result doesn't change.

I also tried `select SQL_NO_CACHE * from table_x` but no luck.

Other tools work ok that's why rather it looks like a bug or what is it at all?

Comment: PyCharm 2017.1.4
Build #PY-171.4694.38, built on June 13, 2017
Licensed to PyCharm Evaluator
Expiration date: July 29, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

If the Data Source works not in **Auto-commit** mode (for the Data Source it is controlled by Auto-commit check box in [General connection settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-console.html#input_icons)) the transaction must be manually committed for the changes to be visible in other transactions.

Since 2017.2.X version [new way of controlling transactions](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2017/06/29/datagrip-2017-2-eap-4) was added to make such things more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by auto-commit option (in my case it was off).

It has to be on otherwise even if you are doing read-only operations you will get the same results.

I guess if auto commit is off PyCharm opens a transaction and never closes it that's why operations works on the same time frame with transaction opening moment.

It has to be a bug. Auto commit could be dangerous, now I am forced to use it which is not convenient and reasonable. Hope it gets fixed soon.